# Retrieve Data from DataTable as Single row parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datarow

I need to retrieve data according to Row by row,

**Example:**

Id | Username | Password 
001 | Xyz | Abc 
002 | ghdfdhjs | dsjkhfjds

As of now, I am getting Single column values(001, Xyz, Abc), which is not giving me desired result.

I need to return result, in such a way by which single row contains all column values (001, Xyz, Abc)

**Trial Code:**

```
DataTableCollection tableCollection = result.Tables;                 
DataTable table = tableCollection["test"];

var rows = table.Rows;
int rowCount = rows.Count;
int colCount = table.Columns.Count;
var results = new object[rowCount, colCount];

       for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
       {                       
       var row = rows[i];
             for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
             {
             results[i, j] = row[j];
             }
       }
return results;
```

**Reference:**

I am trying to manage it by foreach loop with the help of DataRow, which is not working

```
 object[] temp = { };

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
        DataRow row = table.Rows[i];
            foreach (object [] item in row.ItemArray)
                {
                temp = item;                           
                }                       
        }
 return temp;
```

> Cast Exception : System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object
>   of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object[]'

Can someone suggest correct way to get it,

Comment: Use table.AsEnunerable()  : foreach(DataRow row in table.AsEnumerable()){ foreach(object item in row.ItemArray){temp = item;}}

Comment: What result are you expected? You need to store each row into array of objects, right? What do you mean by "single row contains all column values"?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk yes i need to store each row in array of object. I am looking for, to read single row with number of column values.

Comment: What line throws an exception?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk  foreach (object[] item in row.ItemArray)